# What is wrong with my openapi generator gradle setup?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, openapi-generator

I have a multi-module gradle project set up as follows:

root build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "7.2.0" apply false
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    }
}
```

api build.gradle.kts:

```
apply(plugin = "org.openapi.generator")

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
    inputSpec.set("src/main/swagger/api.yml")
    outputDir.set("src/main/kotlin")
    apiPackage.set("com.example.api")
    modelPackage.set("com.example.model")
    invokerPackage.set("com.example.invoker")
    typeMappings.set(
        mapOf(
            "dateLibrary" to "java8"
        )
    )
}
```

And I have a swagger yml at api/src/main/swagger that I can post if need be.

When I can't generate files. I'm seeing this error:

```
> Configure project :api
e: /Users/johnkramer/source/other/openapi-example/api/build.gradle.kts:3:1: Unresolved reference: openApiGenerate
e: /Users/johnkramer/source/other/openapi-example/api/build.gradle.kts:4:5: Unresolved reference: generatorName
e: /Users/johnkramer/source/other/openapi-example/api/build.gradle.kts:5:5: Unresolved reference: inputSpec
e: /Users/johnkramer/source/other/openapi-example/api/build.gradle.kts:6:5: Unresolved reference: outputDir
e: /Users/johnkramer/source/other/openapi-example/api/build.gradle.kts:7:5: Unresolved reference: apiPackage
e: /Users/johnkramer/source/other/openapi-example/api/build.gradle.kts:8:5: Unresolved reference: modelPackage
e: /Users/johnkramer/source/other/openapi-example/api/build.gradle.kts:9:5: Unresolved reference: invokerPackage
e: /Users/johnkramer/source/other/openapi-example/api/build.gradle.kts:10:5: Unresolved reference: typeMappings
```

Can anyone help? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply a plugin in the root `build.gradle.kts` using the `plugins` block, you must also use the `plugins` block to apply that plugin in the child `build.gradle.kts` (see [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl)). No version declaration should be made.

So alter the first line of your `api/build.gradle.kts` to:

```
plugins {
    id("org.openapi.generator")
}
```